DPDK get only packet headers and discard data mbuf
I'm writing a DPDK program that filters only udp/tcp flows using rte_flow, and then I have a queue that holds all the different packet mbufs. But I only need the packet headers, can I somehow configure the program to insert only the packet headers into the queue? Or alternately, immediately free the data portions of the mbufs on receive?
I have a Mellanox connectx 6-dx NIC.
Thanks.
While snooping in the various DPDK docs I saw there's an option for "indirect" buffers that seperate the data from the metadata of the packet. (Mbuf library docs)
MRE:
I'm using the sample DPDK RX/TX program found in https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/rxtx_callbacks.html.

Could you include your MRE within your question, rather than a link? Other websites may change or remove content, which would make this question not make sense in the future.
